# IHP: How can I save multi-select html element values in database?

Tags: haskell, ihp

Let's say, I have a custom form in frontView, with "txtroles" multi-select HTML element.

I submit it to my "UpdateProjectUsersAction" and would like to save it to my "project_user_roles" which have **project_id (foreign id), role_name (text), userid (foreign id)**.

Now, I would like "UpdateProjectUsersAction" to save each multiple values added in "txtroles" to each new rows in my "project_user_roles" table

Comment: This might be helpful: https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/form.html#multi-records-in-a-single-form

Comment: I worked on it. I am receiving following error:

Web/Controller/Roles.hs:75:42
   |
75 |         (invalidRoles, validRoles) -> render EditView { .. }

How can I fix this? @Garrison

Comment: I am still facing this issue. I am performing this in a Edit action, do I have to update my EditRoleAction like it is shown in NewPostAction?